# I need somebody to check this small code (isKeyPressed)

Tags: java, android, arrays, back-button

I have a `PlayState` and a `MenuState`. In `PlayState`, when I click the back-button with my Samsung(Android)-Phone, then it exits the App. What I want it to do when I click the `back-button`, is to get back into `MenuState`.

So in `PlayState`, I tried to set up `isKeyPressed`:

```
@Override
protected void handleInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK));
    gsm.set(new MenuState(gsm));
}
@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
```

I'm not too disappointed, because when I hold the back-button then it goes to `MenuState` and when I let the button go after like 3 seconds, then the `MenuState` even stays. 
Of course this is not the way I want it to work, because nobody wants to hold the button, but just click it.
Tho, when I just click it, then it loops between `MenuState` and `PlayState` (like a framework) and errors/closes the app without a notification.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is not about JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed then write your condition on it, That will help you to solve the problem .

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: But how do i override it in a State?

Comment: For example.                                                          public void onBackPressed(){
    backpress = (backpress + 1);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Press Back again to Exit ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (backpress>1) {
        this.finish();
    }
}